# OpenCV: Cannot load image

Tags: python, opencv

I am quite new in Python. I am trying to load it back into my OCR model (using Google Vision). However, some of the pictures failed to load into the model as it could not load due to the wrong path. It gave me error as below

```
SOURCE_PATH = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/streetlight/recognize_label'
df = pd.DataFrame()
# Read image with opencv
img = cv2.imread(SOURCE_PATH+'/HREX1627.jpg')
# Get image size
height, width = img.shape[:2]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Comment: Try using backslashes in your file path as is typical on Windows (Windows is indicated by your use of C:). Unix uses forward slashes.

Comment: I can use both "/" or "\\" when trying to set the path. I just realized that I set the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the path is wrong.
Try printing the image. If you get a value, it means the file is open.

```py
imgVal = cv2.imread('C:/Users/user/Desktop/streetlight/recognize_label/HREX1627.jpg')
print imgVal
```